# WPF Specific Date Validation

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, date

Our client wants to receive 2 different messages based on invalid dates.  For example, 7/8/14, would be an "invalid date format" where 2/30/2014 is an "invalid date".  Is there a way with C# to notify the user with separate messages? Datetime tryparse identifies both as bad dates, just not sure if I can determine the reason for the bad date without splitting the date out into a string, etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try the match it with Regular Expression, i.e. "one or two digits followed by slash, followed by one or two digits, followed by slash, followed by four digits" it would weed out the "invalid date formats".

My RegEx skills are rusty, but this should ensure the correct format:

```
\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}
```

If it is a match, than its "valid format"

```
static class DateParser
{
    private static readonly Regex DateRegex = new Regex(@"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}");
    public static DateTime Parse(string value)
    {
        if (!DateRegex.IsMatch(value)) throw new DateFormatException();
        return DateTime.Parse(value);
    }
}

internal class DateFormatException : Exception
{
}
```

What WPF has to do with validation?

Comment: Thanks.  I'm a little more concerned about the 2/30/2014.  I was hoping to handle 2 different exceptions.   Still searching..